# How to expand short links in Swift

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection

I have a couple of "http://t.co/gdKG0VJ7kW" short links that I had like to expand and retrieve the host (youtube, flickr and instagram etc). I know I have to use NSURLConnection, otherwise I will only get the short link.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is use `NSURLConnection` to request the short URL. If you implement a `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`, you can use the ridiculous long method:

> `func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection,
>       willSendRequest request: NSURLRequest,
>          redirectResponse redirectResponse: NSURLResponse?) -> NSURLRequest?`

To receive a callback when the shortened URL returns a redirect response to point its original longer form. I think the unshortened URL will be in `request.URL` or you could inspect the headers of the `redirectResponse`.

At that point, if you do not want to finish the request then you can simply call `connection.cancel()` here.